# Do I need to use a npm git command to use git in projects?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, npm-install

Do I need to use `npm i -g git` to use git in a VSC project. I am asking as I just downloaded git from the offical website and now need to use it for my projects

I haven't tried much as I just finished a factory reset from a SSL bug but do not want to have to debug something already (Save it for my projects )

Comment: You can go throw this tutorials
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JJ101D3knE

Answer (score 2):

No, Git is entirely separate from `npm` / Node / Javascript.

The `git` package from `npm` is useful if you want to use Git *from Javascipt.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use git from the official website. You can to go your project path with cmd or git bash and use this :

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/"Your repositories adress" 
git push -u origin main
```